# How would you translate 女将さん

Tags: translation

if they are just being called out to like  「女将さん！」 I read that it was translated Mr./Ms. followed by their profession and was wondering if Ma'am or the like would be acceptable and what variations would be fine.

Comment: It seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than Ma'am you have mentioned, the variations "Hey, Captain!" or "Hey, Boss!" or "Hey, Master!" have appeared in my head. How about that?